# How to generate a variable that corresponds to multiple columns?

Tags: r, date, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have a data set for 10 patients that looks like this:

```
df = data.frame(id=c(1:10),
               event1=sample(1:4, 10, replace=T),
               date1=Sys.Date() - sample(100:500, 10, replace=T), 
               event2=sample(1:4, 10, replace=T),
               date2=Sys.Date() - sample(100:500, 10, replace=T), 
               event3=sample(1:4, 10, replace=T),
               date3=Sys.Date() - sample(100:500, 10, replace=T),
               follow_up=Sys.Date() - sample(10:100, 10, replace=T))
```

Each patient has multiple events, and each event has its corresponding date. An event and date might also be NA if it did not occur. The follow-up date is the last date the patient was checked for events.

I created a variable for outcome bleeding (in this case if an event == 2) as follows:

```
all_vars_quo <- quo(c(event1, event2, event3))

df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(bleeding_no = sum(!!all_vars_quo==2, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(bleeding = if_else(bleeding_no>0,1,0))
```

Now, I would like to add an additional variable "bleeding_date" with the corresponding date of the bleeding. In case more than one bleeding occurred in the same patient, I would like to use the date that is farthest in the past. In case no bleeding occurred, I would like to use the date at follow-up. So far, I was unable to come up with a working piece of code... Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution that is not very aesthetic but should do the job.

I figured that your data could superpose between event and date. Thus, I create a new event (follow-up) and we have "dfevent" with the four events (one is dummy) and dfdate with the four dates.

We keep only the dates that correspond to the event==2, and then, for each row we select the smallest date.

```
df=df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(bleeding_no = sum(!!all_vars_quo==2, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(bleeding = if_else(bleeding_no>0,1,0))%>%
  mutate(eventFU=2)


dfevent=df[,c(2,4,6,11)]
dfdate=df[,c(3,5,7,8)]

dfdatef=dfdate

dfdatef[!dfevent==2]=NA

df=cbind(df,date=apply(dfdatef,1,min,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you Félix, this does the job!

Answer (score 0):

I think that will do, using `dplyr::case_when`

```
df <- df %>% 
        mutate(bleeding_date = case_when(bleeding == 1 ~ min(date1, date2, date3),
                                         bleeding != 1 ~ follow_up
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you Guilherme. Using case_when like this gives the date farthest in the past, but not specifically linked to the corresponding bleeding event like it should..